# Equivalent of "du" command on a Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm looking for a solution to recursively get the size of all my folders on a Amazon S3 bucket which has a lot of embedded folders.

The perfect example is the Linux `du --si` command:

```
12M ./folder1
50M ./folder2
50M ./folder2/subfolder1
etc...
```

I'm also open to any graphical tool.  Is there any command or AWS API for that?

Answer (score 20):

Use [`awscli`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html)

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket --recursive --human-readable --summarize
```

Comment: aws s3 ls --summarize --human-readable --recursive s3:/xyz##-logs/* gives error: zsh: no matches found: s3://xyz##-logs/*

Comment: @AshishKarpe quote the s3 url

Answer (score 4):

```
s3cmd du -H s3://bucket-name
```

This command tells you the size of the bucket (human readable). If you want to know the sizes of subfolders you can list the folders in the bucket (s3cmd ls s3://bucket-name) and then iterate through them.